# How do I keep reactiveVars template scoped?

Tags: javascript, meteor

It is said that using too many `Sessions` is bad because it "pollutes the global namespace". Now, I don't exactly know what that means (I can easily think of many more names to use...) but I have started to use `ReactiveVar` instead, but it seems complicated and buggy, so I wonder what the benefits are.

For example, this simple use case throws an error:

```
Template.AddingItem.onRendered(function() {
    this.addingItem = new ReactiveVar(false)
})

Template.AddingItem.events({

    'click .add-new-item.button': function(event, template) {
        var addingItem = template.addingItem.get()
        if (addingItem === false) {
            template.addingItem.set(true)
        }
        else {
            template.addingItem.set(false)
        }
     }
})

Template.AddingItem.helpers({

    isAddingItem: function() {
        return Template.instance().addingItem.get()
    },
 })
```

Template:

```
{{#if isAddingItem}}
    <div>Showing something</div>
{{/if}}
```

Sometimes the helper runs before `onRendered` and can't return anything, so the page bugs out. This is literally the easiest use case for `ReactiveVar` and it can't even do that right? What am I missing?

Comment: I'd suggest changing the title of this question to something more helpful to future Googlers...something like "Best way to keep reactiveVars template scoped"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Template.onCreated`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onCreated) to create `reactiveVars`.

You must instantiate your reactiveVar *before* any controller code runs so that Tracker can correctly track your `reactiveVar`. `onRendered` is best used for functions that manipulate the DOM and runs too late to reliably ensure `addingItem` exists when the helper runs, as you encountered.

That's what `onCreated` is best for. That way your reactiveVar is ensured to exist when your helpers/controller code runs.

```
Template.AddingItem.onCreated(function() {
  this.addingItem = new ReactiveVar(false)
})
```

And for future reference, `Sessions` are actually just `reactiveVars` with a global scope...there's nothing magical about them. It's `reactiveVars` all the way down.